# Functional equation for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sinh(cn)^{-s}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, functional-equations, hyperbolic-functions

Does anyone know of any kind of functional equation (or closed form) for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sinh(cn)^{-s}$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant? I've been messing around with it off and on for a while now, but haven't been able to come up with anything particularly nice. Any ideas or references where such series are considered would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems that if $s$ is an integer, the closed form  could express as a linear combination of  some ugly q-digamma functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, I've tried writing out what a general form expressed that way (at least for $s\in\mathbb{Z}$) would look like, but it always ends up being something really, really terrible and entirely an extrapolation of things WolframAlpha gives me.